# Disable internet access

Tags: windows-7

I have a 1meg internet connection which goes directly to my Acer Windows 7 laptop. That connection gets distributed to three wireless devices by the Microsoft Virtual miniport adapter. However,  I would like to know if  there is any command line which can disable the internet connection which a given wireless device receives.

Ideally, it should block the internet connection going to any one of the three devices that I choose. While the remaining two devices continue to receive internet connection. I would prefer to choose the device that will have its internet connection disabled either by IP Address or MAC Address

Answer (score 1):

This does do it:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

Change `Local Area Connection` for the connection name you want to disable.

Remember that you will need **Admin rights** in order to execute the command.

Comment: Hey thanks Jerry. But I may not have been clear enough about what the command line should do. Ideally, it should block the internet connection going to any one of the three devices that I choose. While the remaining two devices continue to receive internet connection. I would prefer to choose the device that will have its internet connection disabled either by IP Address or MAC Address.